# How does the typewriter work?

Tags: fringe

In several episodes, shape-shifters use a typewriter to communicate between universes.

How does it work? Does the mirror play an important part in it?

Comment: Very well, thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [Fringe wiki](http://fringepedia.net/wiki/Selectric_251):

> In *Entrada*, Walter refers to the typewriter as a quantum entangled
>   telegraph.

Other than quantum entanglement being involved, I don't think anything else (even whether or not the mirror is needed) has been revealed.

Comment: The mirror is just to see that someone is "typing". As for the quantum entanglement, I'm tempted to says that if that were the case, then the keys would also move. Its probably easier to record keys moving and edit that onto the mirror than to set up the motors to have the keys move on their own.

Comment: @Teknophilia It could be the hammers that are entangled, then the keys wouldn't need to move  ;)